# Merging Items each with 2 Rows for calculations specific to Item's Row 1 and Row 2

Tags: r, dplyr

I've managed to manipulate my data to reduce multiple Buy/Sells for a current item into just 2 rows, one for BUY and one for SELL. So, my dataframe currently looks like that:

```
Market   Type `After Fees Collapsed` `AFC Signed`
 <chr>  <chr>                  <dbl>        <dbl>
ITEM_1    BUY             0.03220841  -0.03220841
ITEM_1   SELL             0.03251323   0.03251323
ITEM_2    BUY             0.05522072  -0.05522072
ITEM_2   SELL             0.01160392   0.01160392
ITEM_3    BUY             0.05707432  -0.05707432
ITEM_3   SELL             0.05759784   0.05759784
ITEM_4    BUY             0.03221925  -0.03221925
ITEM_4   SELL             0.03217333   0.03217333
ITEM_5    BUY             0.05070265  -0.05070265
ITEM_5   SELL             0.05118556   0.05118556
```

The AFC Signed column is simply the "After Fees Collapsed" column multiplied by -1 for buys. This was so I could calculate the Net result by running the code below. However, I believe that with the right answer to this question, I can do away with the AFC signed column and work straight with the values from my BUY and SELL rows.

```
... %>%
    summarise(Nett = sum(`AFC Signed`)
```

What I'd like to do is collapse the ITEM_# into a single row, with a column for "Nett" (derived from the specific ITEM's SELL-BUY) and one for "% Nett" (derived from the specific ITEM's (SELL-BUY)/BUY). The output would thus look like the below (numbers are made up):

```
Market    Nett  `% Nett`
ITEM_1    0.03      10%
ITEM_2    -0.4     -15%
ITEM_3     1.5    7.33%
ITEM_4   0.003    2.45%
ITEM_%  -1.468  -4.141%
```

Comment: Code snippet formation is wasteful of space. They won't run ... don't use for R code.

Answer (score 2):

The basic idea for this kind of thing is generally (with `d` being your dataset)

```
aggregate(`AFC Signed` ~ Market, d, sum)
```

But actually you're better off fixing your data model. From the start your data frame should have been:

```
item  buy_value  sell_value
...   ...        ...
```

rather than

```
item  type  value
id1   buy   ...
id1   sell  ...
```

Then you'd be able to simply do

```
d$net_pct = (d$sell_value - d$buy_value) / d$buy_value
```

---

Edit for completeness, how to fix the data frame (this is all trivial):

```
d = d[order(d$Market),]
d2 = d[d$Type == 'BUY',]
d3 = d[d$Type == 'SELL',]
all(d2$Market == d3$Market) # should be true
d2$`Sell after Fees Collapsed` = d3$`After Fees Collapsed`
d2$net = d2$`Sell after Fees Collapsed` - d2$`After Fees Collapsed`
d2$net_pct = d2$net / d2$`After Fees Collapsed`
```

Comment: Doesn't seem like this is really an answer, although I can understand not wanting it to lose the formating.

Comment: I'm just stating the proper way. You can use advanced ugly hacks or you can reformat the input data, which is much easier, particularly if it is paired properly, and then everything become trivial. Also, note that the super-but-ugly hack will insert not readily identifiable junk in the results table if the input data isn't paired properly.

Comment: @n.caillou I understand that a better dataset would be ideal, however this is a dataset that is exported from an online source, where I have no control over the format

Comment: @Shawn The answer explains how to reformat the data. It is all the more important to check that the data is correctly paired if it comes from a third party

Answer (score 2):

```
  aggregate(.~Market,dat[1:3],function(x)c(a<-diff(x),a/x[1]))
   Market Type.M Type.V2 X.AfterFeesCollapsed..M X.AfterFeesCollapsed..V2
 1 ITEM_1      1       1             0.000304820              0.009463988
 2 ITEM_2      1       1            -0.043616800             -0.789862936
 3 ITEM_3      1       1             0.000523520              0.009172602
 4 ITEM_4      1       1            -0.000045920             -0.001425235
 5 ITEM_5      1       1             0.000482910              0.009524354
```

Comment: You can get rid of the extra columns

Answer (score 1):

An approach with `dplyr` (which you are apperently already using):

```
d %>% 
  group_by(Market) %>% 
  summarise(Nett = After_Fees_Collapsed[Type == 'SELL'] - After_Fees_Collapsed[Type == 'BUY'],
            pNett = 100 * Nett / After_Fees_Collapsed[Type == 'BUY'])
```

which gives:

> ```
> # A tibble: 5 x 3
>   Market        Nett       pNett
>   <fctr>       <dbl>       <dbl>
> 1 ITEM_1  0.00030482   0.9463988
> 2 ITEM_2 -0.04361680 -78.9862936
> 3 ITEM_3  0.00052352   0.9172602
> 4 ITEM_4 -0.00004592  -0.1425235
> 5 ITEM_5  0.00048291   0.9524354
> ```

---

Used data:

```
d <- structure(list(Market = c("ITEM_1", "ITEM_1", "ITEM_2", "ITEM_2", "ITEM_3", "ITEM_3", "ITEM_4", "ITEM_4", "ITEM_5", "ITEM_5"), 
                    Type = c("BUY", "SELL", "BUY", "SELL", "BUY", "SELL", "BUY", "SELL", "BUY", "SELL"),
                    After_Fees_Collapsed = c(0.03220841, 0.03251323, 0.05522072, 0.01160392, 0.05707432, 0.05759784, 0.03221925, 0.03217333, 0.05070265, 0.05118556),
                    AFC_Signed = c(-0.03220841, 0.03251323, -0.05522072, 0.01160392, -0.05707432, 0.05759784, -0.03221925, 0.03217333, -0.05070265, 0.05118556)),
               .Names = c("Market", "Type", "After_Fees_Collapsed", "AFC_Signed"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```